# How do I approach a classification problem where one of the classes is defined by 'not any of the others'

Tags: machine-learning, classification

Suppose that I am interested in three classes $c_1$, $c_2$, $c_3$. But my dataset actually contains several more real classes $(c_j)_{j=4}^n$.

The obvious answer is to define a new class $\hat c_4$ that refers to all classes $c_j$, $j>3$ but I suspect this is not a good idea since the samples in $\hat c_4$ will be rare and not very similar to each other.

To visualize what I'm trying to say, suppose I have the following two variable space and the classes $c_1$, $c_2$, $c_3$, $\hat c_4= \bigcup_{j=4}^n c_j$ are depicted in red, til, green and black respectively. This is how I suspect my data would look like.

[image]

Is there any standard way to approach this problem? What would be the most efficient classifier and why?

Comment: Consider using one vs. rest https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiclass_classification#One-vs.-rest

Comment: You may want to explore [positive-unlabeled models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-class_classification). It looks like a similar problem, except it is multiclass, not binary as most PU problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a two-step approach, using the idea of the $\hat{c_4}$ class you mentioned.

In the first step, use a binary classifier(trained on the whole dataset) to decide if a sample belongs to the class $\hat{c_4}$ (i.e. in any non-interesting class). For this, step you could also take a look in [outlier detection](http://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-identify-outliers-in-your-data/) methods, if the samples belonging in the "interesting" classes are much different than the rest.

If the result is negative, move on to the next step, a new classifier trained only on samples belonging in the classes $c_1,c_2,c_3$ and use that prediction as your final one.

I think that even using a simple clustering approach as a first step (e.g. 4-clustering [k-means](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html) using as initial centroid values the average centroid $cent_j = \frac{\sum\limits_{x_i\in D: y_i=j}x_i}{\sum\limits_{x_i\in D: y_i=j}1}$  for each $c_1,c_2,c_3, \hat{c_4}$), would still be useful.

Comment: Bogas suggestion is great if you do not have much class overlap. Otherwise, go with a multi-label model.

Comment: This is a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_classifiers